# Boto3 and DynamoDB - How to mimic Aggregation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have a table in DynamoDB in the below format:

| DeviceId (PK) | SensorDataType | SensorValue | CurrentTime (SK) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BSMD002 | HeartRate | 86 | 2021-03-13 14:50:17.292663 |
| BSMD002 | HeartRate | 106 | 2021-03-13 14:50:17.564644 |
| BSMD002 | HeartRate | 97 | 2021-03-13 14:50:17.854391 |

I am pulling the data from this table using boto3 and want to create a new table basis user input ( DeviceId, Date Range).This table will have sensortype wise data - Max,min and avg grouped by minute.

I know DynamoDB doesn't support aggregation and using Streams + Lambda is the more efficient way. But want to understand if there is a way to do this in boto3. So far have worked pulling the data as per below code.

```py
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('BSMDataTable')

devicetag = input(" Enter the Device ID to find: ").upper()
datefrom = input("Enter Starting Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
dateto = input("Enter Ending Date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")

fe = Key('CurrentTime').between(datefrom,dateto) & Key('DeviceId').eq(devicetag);
response = table.query(
                KeyConditionExpression=fe
            )
for i in response['Items']:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Please put some sample data in the table I've edited into the post and tell us what exactly you're struggling with, this looks like a promising start. Also in the code it seems like the TimeStamp column is named CurrentTime?

Comment: Yes, CurrentTime is timestamp.

Comment: DeviceId CurrentTime SensorType Reading
A001 3/13/2021 11:01 Temp 82
A002 3/13/2021 11:01 Heart 92

Comment: Please edit your question and the time format is a problem, you won't be able to really do range queries on them - store it in ISO8601 format or Unix Epoch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually very close. All that's missing is the aggregation of the items from the response.

Here's an example for that.
We first group the items by the minute and then calculate the statistics for each minute.

```py
import statistics
import itertools

# Sample data
response = {
    "Items": [
        {"DeviceId": "BSMD002", "SensorDataType": "HeartRate", "SensorValue": 86, "CurrentTime": "2021-03-13 14:50:17.123"},
        {"DeviceId": "BSMD002", "SensorDataType": "HeartRate", "SensorValue": 100, "CurrentTime": "2021-03-13 14:50:18.123"},
        {"DeviceId": "BSMD002", "SensorDataType": "HeartRate", "SensorValue": 19, "CurrentTime": "2021-03-13 14:51:17.123"},
    ]
}

# Group the response by items per minute
items_by_minute = itertools.groupby(
    response["Items"], 
    key=lambda x: x["CurrentTime"][:16]  #  The first 16 characters including the minute
)

# Calculate the statistics for each minute
for minute, items in items_by_minute:
    values_per_minute = [item["SensorValue"] for item in items]
    
    avg = statistics.mean(values_per_minute)
    min_value = min(values_per_minute)
    max_value = max(values_per_minute)
    
    print(f"Minute: {minute} / Average {avg} / Min {min_value} / Max {max_value}")
```

Output

```
Minute: 2021-03-13 14:50 / Average 93 / Min 86 / Max 100
Minute: 2021-03-13 14:51 / Average 19 / Min 19 / Max 19
```

Comment: An additional query on this. If I want to do a nested Groupby... first on SensorDataType and then on Minute agg, how can this be achieved..

Comment: Change the lambda-expression to `lambda x: f"{x['SensorDataType']}_{x["CurrentTime"][:16]}"`

Comment: Iam making some basic mistake..SensorType Grouping and then min aggregation is not working.. `items_by_minute = sorted(col, key=lambda x: (x["SensorDataType"],x["CurrentTime"][:16]) )
items_by_minute = itertools.groupby(col, key=lambda x: (x["SensorDataType"],x["CurrentTime"][:16]))`

Comment: Can you please create a second question for that? Adding more sub-questions makes this less useful for future readers. Please include a minimum verifiable example, e.g. the code in my answer with your additions and a clear explanation what works and doesn't work. If my answer solved your problem so far, feel free to accept it.